# Are scheduled UILocalNotifications part of iOS device backup?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I mean, our app schedules a couple of local notifications. User makes a backup of the system and restores it on a new device. Will previously scheduled local notifications fire on the new system, or do we need to reschedule them again on the new system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I forced myself to do the test. The result:

**YES - scheduled local notifications are part of backup**, this means they are restored and scheduled on the new device. The restore overwrites any previously scheduled local notifications for the same app on the target device. Even **icon badge number is preserved in backup and restored to the new device** - showed on the icon.

Answer (score 0):

I think that can be restore/copy to new device, or maybe you have to use new device to test this workflow ...

Comment: oh yes, I know. I am just asking, if anybody has the results.